# How to raise the cake high for pound cakes

Tags: baking

We are baking pound cake. I am all happy about the taste, but I have two problems, please help.

1. After we bake the cake and take it out, we observed after a week my top layer of the cake is moist and the bottom we see all the oil is settled down, making the cake look oily from bottom. The mid region of cake is very dry and not much moist. Is there anything I am missing to make my cake evenly moist and less dry?
2. How do I get high raise of the cake? It is a good raise but not as much as other cakes I have seen around, is there some magic needed in there to make my cake raise high?

Comment: Two (largely unrelated) questions -> two posts, please! (Hint: you *might* even get more votes that way.) And before you [edit] your post, please take the [tour] and browse our [help], this should give you some pointers.

Comment: And we need to know the recipe plus what you did with it!

Comment: And in my family the real problem wouldn’t be the condition after a week - it would be long gone.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help with your second question. Pound cake is not supposed to rise as much as other cakes. It is "heavy" not light and fluffy. A pound cake recipe has a greater proportion of fat than other types because it is specially meant to store for several days without drying out.

As for the soft top: the mushy, moist "crust" that forms after a day or two was our favourite part of poundcake and fruit breads.